# ActiveMQ - ReplicatedLevelDB - Backup and Recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, leveldb

What is the most reliable way for performing **data backup and recovery** for **LevelDB** database?

We are using **replicatedLevelDB** for persisting the messages in **ActiveMQ cluster**. The entire infrastructure is deployed in **AWS cloud**.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because LevelDB is journaled, a consistent snapshot (using LVM, Btrfs, or other tools) of the data on disk should be a safe backup. If you cannot take a consistent snapshot, then your only alternatives are stopping the application to copy the data or using an application-native backup method.

Copying the data files inconsistently may cause data loss.